# spring mvc restful login

Tags: spring, rest, redirect, model-view-controller

I am new to spring,as i am facing some problem,how to redirect to registration page when login credentials is successfull else return user does not exist message. I am using spring rest and client is ajax.here is my sample code

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST,
                                consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Login> login(@RequestBody Login login,UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder)
{
            System.out.println("Checking Login Credentials...");

            boolean isValid=loginServiceBo.checkUserLogin(login);

            if(isValid)
            {
                System.out.println("Found...");
                return new ResponseEntity<Login>(login, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            }
            System.out.println("Not Found...");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Spring rest service, so you need to send status code to your client, and according those status code you can redirect in client side.

```
if(isValid)
            {
                System.out.println("Found...");
                return new ResponseEntity<Login>(login, HttpStatus.OK);

            }
            System.out.println("Not Found...");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Ajax

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("/login",{username: "xxxxx",password: "xxxxxx"},
    function(response){
        //redirect to registration page
    }, function(error) {
        //show user does not exist message
    });
});
```